# Excel VBA to select new data and transfer to the next blank line in another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have found a couple places that this has been touched on but I am not a programmer by any means so I am having difficulty using what I have found. I have been teaching myself VBA for access but I am very lost as to how to go about this in excel.

I have two work sheets in my workbook. One is called "Field" the other is called "DTE" in the Field sheet I have employees tracking the number of ballasts that are installed at a certain job site. The DTE is more indepth and is the sheet that our customer needs. Our guys are not at all tech savvy so I need to find the easiest way (one button click type of situation) to have the information transferred from "Field" to "DTE".

Here is some information on the data:
Field contains three tables (they are currently left to right but I can make them top to bottom if that is messing the codes up)
The first table is for ballasts, second for fixtures. There third is not necessary for this question.
There are multiple types of ballasts and fixtures which is where the difficulty comes in.

For example:
I need to have certain information transferred over, on the field form the guys type the location as well as how many of each type of ballast/fixture. In the DTE I need this information to be arranged slightly differently.
If the Row in the field form looks like this:

Location Ballasts 1 Ballasts 2   The second looks like this:

Hall  3        4

and then I need the DTE to look like this

Location  Quantity  Type

Hall        3       Ballasts 1

Hall        4       Ballasts 2

I know this is extremely in depth and I apologize in advanced because this is much more difficult than I wanted to make it but if anyone could help I would really appreciate it. Thank you so much!
(Also if you think another answer may help please link me to it, I have tried to use many of them and alter them to fix my tables but I just come up with a ton of errors. Thank you again!)

Comment: What Excel version are you using? Do you have the Get & Transform option? If so - have a look at it!

Comment: I believe it is 2010 but I am not positive. Also, I will check that out and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: If that is the case, you have those options in the Power Query add-in